# MySQL 1175 Error While Using Primary Keys

Tags: update, primary-key, mysql-5.6, errors

What would cause the error 1175 that starts out with: `You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column...`. The problem I have is that I did include a `WHERE` clause with key columns: `WHERE a.a_id = b.b_id`

`a_id` and `b_id` are the only key columns in their respective tables.

```
START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE table_a a, table_b b
    SET a.update_me = b.update_from_me
WHERE a.a_id = b.b_id;
SELECT * FROM a;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it's quite simple.

You have enabled the safe update mode (as the error stated). Your statement has a where clause, right. But it's interpreted as a `JOIN` not as a `WHERE` as you provide a syntax like a `INNER JOIN`.

Your code:

```
UPDATE table_a a, table_b b
SET a.update_me = b.update_from_me
WHERE a.a_id = b.b_id;
```

Is technically the same (and interpreted as such) as this one:

```
UPDATE a
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b
        ON a.a_id = b.b_id;b_id
SET a.update_me = b.update_from_me;
```

Which means, there is no really `WHERE`. You update the whole table `table_a`, which is matching with the other table `table_b`.

If you really want to achieve this, you can disable the `Safe Update Mode` for this query using this code:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE table_a a, table_b b
SET a.update_me = b.update_from_me
WHERE a.a_id = b.b_id;
```

Anyway, your mysql server is running with `mysqld --safe-updates` or `mysqld --i-am-a-dummy` which is pretty the same option.

You can check if this is really enabled using one of the following commands:

```
SELECT @@SQL_SAFE_UPDATES
-- or
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_safe_updates'
```

By the way, you can also try a workaround to get the update done. `Safe Update Mode` requires a `WHERE` or a `LIMIT`. Which will limit the impact of the Update. Another idea can be to use a pretty high `LIMIT` for your `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE table_a a, table_b b
SET a.update_me = b.update_from_me
WHERE a.a_id = b.b_id
LIMIT 100000;
```

If the `Safe Update Mode` is enabled, you need to be aware of `DELETE`'s too. They need both. A `WHERE` and a `LIMIT`. See the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates).